# use environment variables in contextconfig of talend

Tags: environment-variables, talend

We want our talend job to use environment variables as parameters. 
Is it possible to use environment variables in the contextconfig of a talend job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several techniques are discussed in this thread https://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=8437

Below is a Java snippet which can be used in most Talend Components (like tJava) to read an environment variable into a context variable

context.EXAMPLE = System.getProperty("EXAMPLE");